# How to differ from different images in iPhone programing

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I have a view with some images. I want to know which image I selected. If I select an image, it will come to same method if I select another image.

On every image I select the "touchesEnded:" method is executed.
Is there away to differ between the images?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enymerate throught all views:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
// Enumerate through all the touch objects.
    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {
        //Enumerate through all subviews
        for (UIView *subView in [self.view subviews])
        {
            if (CGRectContainsPoint([subView frame], [touch locationInView:self.view]))
            {
                //Found touched view
                /*Optional: you can set to each UIImageView tag and check it here
                switch (subView.tag)
                {
                    case 1:
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                */
            }
        }
     }
 }
```